# Jquery drag list update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that uses Jquery UI drag drop sortable but when I drop one of options into a list I want to be able to tell where it is in the list like the following does:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

Only thing is I am not sure how to do this around my current Jquery and when I tried I failed and it kept giving me [object] [object] errors :)

**Here is my code:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
$( "#example1, #example2" ).sortable({
stop: function(event, ui) { 
var item = $(ui.item).parent().attr("id"); 
var moveid = $(ui.item).attr("id");
var sortableid = $(ui.item).sortable;
alert(item);
alert(moveid);
}}).disableSelection();
    });
</script>


<div class="box">
<ul id="example1" class='droptrue'>
<li id="id1" class="ui-state-default boxclass">ABC</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
<ul id="example2" class='droptrue'>
<li id="id2" class="ui-state-default boxclass">XYZ</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If any of you would be able to show me in the right direction of how to do this using javascript or jquery, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you want out of this? the index of the element relative to the parent container? If that's the case, we can test for `$(ui.item).parent().children().index(ui.item)` which will give us the index within the list where it was dropped.

Comment: Well I have a column in MYSQL which allows the project manager to sort the list to how he/she wants to - the list is numbered e.g. (1 - 200) so when I run mysql queries I order by this column. What I want is to be able to find out what row number or where the current drag is on the list so I can update this column which in turn will update the front end list. The example URL given has an example of ordering a drag and I was trying to do this with my current list.. - the code you have given me works, thank you very much for answering my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume our list items have a class of, 'list_item'.

HTML ->

```
<ul>
   <li class="list_item" id="some_unique_identifier1"> List Item 197 </li>
   <li class="list_item" id="some_unique_identifier2"> List Item 3 </li>
   <li class="list_item" id="some_unique_identifier3"> List Item 55 </li>
   <li class="list_item" id="some_unique_identifier4"> List Item 104 </li>
   ...etc
</ul>
```

jQuery Sortable ->

```
$(function(){
  $('ul').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui){
      var list_item_id = $(ui.item).prop('id');
      var list_item_position =$(ui.item).parent().children().index(ui.item);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/my/controller.ext',
        data: { 'id' : list_item_id, 'list_position' : list_item_position}
      });
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

The PHP Controller will be the most difficult part. You'll have to (obviously) update the row that we moved, and we'll have to update all other rows that come **after** the row with +1, because, well, they'll all gain 1 index position in the list. creating the proper workflow from here is up to you, but you have the jist of what's needed from a jQuery Sortable perspective.

*As a side note*

And in all honesty, I probably wouldn't send a bunch of $.ajax over to update the table I'm working with. I'd create a temporary table to store all the values, removing items that are submitted more than once so you don't have duplicates. Then I'd require the user to save the position's at some point with a submit button (or a per-determined interval). Then I'd update the real table with the values found in the temporary table.  I'd also drop the temporary table after we're done with it.